# Entity Framework Error - The query syntax is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to run a simple custom query that is returned into a custom object, however, I keep running into an error and I have no idea what is wrong. The query runs just fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Nullable<int> EligibleCredits { get; set;}
    public Nullable<int> ReadyForSubmissionCredits { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RedeemedCredits { get; set; }
}
```

Main Method:

```
var query = @"SELECT 
    (select count(*) from MyTable where UserId = @userId and [Status] = 0 and Year(EarnDate) >= (select Year(getdate()) -@years)) as EligibleCredits,
    (select count(*) from MyTable where UserId = @userId and [Status] = 1 and Year(EarnDate) >= (select Year(getdate()) -@years)) as ReadyForSubmissionCredits,
    (select count(*) from MyTable where UserId = @userId and [Status] = 2 and Year(EarnDate) >= (select Year(getdate()) -@years)) as RedeemedCredits";

var objectQuery = new ObjectQuery<MyClass>(query, ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext);
objectQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("userId", userId));
objectQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("years", years));

return objectQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

The error that I get is:

> The query syntax is not valid. Near term '*', line 2, column 39.

This query runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

Also, according to this article, I'm doing it correctly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Are `userId` and `years` `int`s? Are they `nullable`?

Comment: First, why aren't you using EF rather than a raw SQL query?  Second, your raw SQL query could be improved with a structure like `select count(UserId), CASE WHEN [Status] = 0 THEN 'EligibleCredits' WHEN [Status] = 1 THEN 'ReadyForSubmissionCredits' WHEN [Status] = 2 THEN 'RedeemedCredits' END AS CreditType from MyTable where UserId = @userId and [Status] IN (0,1,2) and Year(EarnDate) >= (select Year(getdate()) -@years)) GROUP BY [Status]`.

Comment: Apparently **Entity SQL query** is not the same as *SQL query*. The exception is thrown by EF SQL query parser. Rather than obsolete `ObjectContext` APIs, use the EF6 preferred `context.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(...)` - look at the help how to specify parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the EntityFramework query parser. All I can do, is to provide you with a workaround (which BTW, may even run faster):

```
var query = @"SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as EligibleCredits,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as ReadyForSubmissionCredits,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as RedeemedCredits
    FROM MyTable 
       WHERE UserId = @userId 
       AND Year(EarnDate) >= Year(getdate()) - @years";

var objectQuery = new ObjectQuery<MyClass>(query, ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext);
objectQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("userId", userId));
objectQuery.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("years", years));

return objectQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that if `this` is an instance of `DbContext`, you can simplify your code as follows:

```
var query = @"SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as EligibleCredits,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as ReadyForSubmissionCredits,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as RedeemedCredits
    FROM MyTable 
       WHERE UserId = @p0 -- <== NOTE THE PARAM NAME HERE AND BELOW
       AND Year(EarnDate) >= Year(getdate()) - @p1";
return new this.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(query, userId, years).FirstOrDefault();
```

**This last approach also works with your original query**.

Comment: Essentially the bug is the fact that it cannot fill out the null object?

Comment: @Bojan No, it's parsing the SQL statement. EF needs to parse the query so it knows how to assign the output to objects in .NET. Normally, `objectQuery.ToTraceString()` would output the generated SQL statement, but in this case, it throws the same exception, even before execution takes place.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteStoreQuery worked for me, for the same error. Sample below:

```
IList<MyClass> contactList =
            (((IObjectContextAdapter) model).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyClass>(strString))
            .ToList<MyClass>();
```